# Pointer to Elements of an Array printing the memory address rather than the value of the element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am currently writing a program for a class that takes user input to either add or remove a number from a dynamic array, and then print all the values of the array in ascending order.

From what I have already researched, all I need to do to get the value of the element in the array to print is to ensure the dereference operator is inserted next to the pointer name. However, when done as below (*newArray[i]) I get a compile-time error saying that the operand to the right of the '*' must be a pointer, even though newArray is declared as pointer at the beginning of the function.

```
void output(int *arrayPtr, int size){
int small;
int i, j;
int *newArray;
newArray = new int[size];

for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    *newArray[i] = arrayPtr[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    small = *newArray[i];
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if (*newArray[j] < small){
            *newArray[j] = small;
        }
        std::cout << small;
    }
    int number = small;
    removeNumber(*& arrayPtr, number, size);
}
```

}

I feel like there is something totally obvious I am missing, but I would greatly appreciate any help or ideas!!

Comment: The `[]` is a dereference operator.  `a[i]` and `*(a+i)` are alternative syntax for the same operation. Pick one or the other, not both at once!

Comment: Please don't forget to release the memory of what  you allocated (if you're switching  - of the old object..)

Comment: @evenro Ahh, thanks!! Had that in my other functions, but totally forgot to put it in this one!

Answer (score 1):

```
 small = *newArray[i];
```

That should just be:

```
 small = newArray[i];
```

(Same thing in the other places you compare/assign `*newArray[i]`

What your first operation is doing is first dereferencing newArray, which means it gets the value of the first element in the array, and then attempting to index that.  The element is not a pointer, so this of course fails.  When you index, it also implicitly dereferences the pointer.  You could also write:

```
small = *(newArray + i);
```

However, generally you only use pointer arithmetic when you need the actual pointer, since indexing is easier to read if you need the value.

Going through your code, a few other things seem off:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    *newArray[i] = arrayPtr[i];
}
```

This might compile but I don't think it is right, I'm guessing you mean:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    newArray[i] = arrayPtr[i];
}
```

Also:

```
removeNumber(*& arrayPtr, number, size);
```

While this is technically correct, `*&` first returns a pointer reference, then turns around and dereferences it again.  I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler optimizes it away anyway, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: wouldn't that just set the value of small to the memory address of that element?

Comment: No, `small = newArray+i` would do that.  Also, looking through it looks like you do a lot of odd things, give me a minute to try to sort through them.

Comment: As far as the '*&' goes, my instructor provided us with a header file to use for this program, and that was how the function was prototyped so I just went with it.

Also, your guess was indeed correct

Comment: I'm not sure if I am just totally missing something or what, but after changing all instances of 'small = *newArray[i];' with 'small = newArray[i];' , I still get the memory address printed out.

Comment: Responding to your header file comment, using `&` in a parameter list means that the parameter is passed by reference instead of by value.  For practical purposes, this means that rather than creating a new variable in the function scope for you to use, you are instead editing the variable that was passed itself.  You don't need to do anything special when actually calling the function.

Comment: @user3487336 For your second comment, are you sure arrayPtr is being filled correctly?  There isn't any reason that your code would be assigning the pointers in the array to small, so it's likely that the int values they point to are themselves pointers.